# How to group events objects under a single shared date with group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am attempting to list events that share the same date under a single date table header.

I came across [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720513/listing-objects-under-the-date-they-were-created) which I think has guided me in the right direction, but not entirely solved my problem.

I'm using the following code in my view:

```
<% @events = @organization.events.group_by{|x| x.when} %>
<% @events.each do |listing| %>
    <p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <%= listing.when %>
                </th>
            </tr>
                <% listing.each do |list| %>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%= list.name %> given by
                            <% list.vips.each do |v| %>
                                <%= v.name %>
                            <% end %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>   
        </table>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

The error I get is "undefined method `when' for #Array:0x007fc781f9b000"

When I use the console, @events prints out the following:

```
{Mon, 24 Aug 2015 00:00:00 UTC +00:00=>[#<Event id: 7, when: "2015-08-24 00:00:00", organization_id: 4, created_at: "2015-08-24 05:42:59", updated_at: "2015-08-24 05:42:59", name: "Initial Captain's Brief", vip_id: 1>, #<Event id: 8, when: "2015-08-24 00:00:00", organization_id: 4, created_at: "2015-08-24 05:43:08", updated_at: "2015-08-24 05:43:08", name: "Ryan's Event", vip_id: 2>]}
```

What I really don't understand is, when I replace

```
<%= listing.when %>
```

With

```
<%= listing %>
```

I get a new error saying "undefined method `name' for Mon, 24 Aug 2015 00:00:00 UTC +00:00:Time"

**Overall**

- Is the object being returned by @organizations.events.group_by{|x| x.when} a hash with a *key* of Mon, Aug 24 2015 and multiple *values* consisting of the events matching that *key*?
- Is there a way to correctly code my example such that it has a single date as a table header and then event listings in the rows beneath it without errors?

Comment: One way to debug this  is to use @variable.inspect . For example, do a events.inspect and you will see what's going on in there

Answer (score 0):

To do what you're attempting, you could use listing in its current state, but change the each method to define the key and value of the hash.

```
<% @events.each do |timestamp, listing| %>
....
<%= timestamp # in place of listing.when %>
```

For your overall questions

- Yes, it is a hash in this case
- Not entirely certain what you mean here.  Isn't this what you're already doing in your example snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [webpage](http://www.rubyfleebie.com/how-to-display-a-collection-grouped-by-an-attribute-value-in-rails/) that answered my question.

The code should look something like the following:

```
<% @events = @organization.events.group_by(&:when) %>
    <% @events.each_pair do |date, event| %>
    <p>
        <%= date.strftime("%A, %e %b %Y") %>
    </p>
    <% event.each do |list| %>
    <p>
        <%= list.name %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So, my understanding is that yes, the group_by method creates a hash pair. The key of this hash is the date (Aug 24th in this case), and the value of the key is the event object itself. So I have to iterate over each value of the key in a way that allows me to access its attributes. The each_pair method allows me to do this.